# Using in app purchase to unlock iPad UI?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a universal app as a scaled iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804047/running-a-universal-app-as-a-scaled-iphone-app)

I'm going to be trying a more creative business model for one of my newer apps. I originally built the app as a universal application and then shipped it as iPhone only-although it still runs scaled, of course. I was thinking about using IAP to unlock a true, full HD iPad UI. Has anyone done this before? Thoughts? I like this idea because it still allows for the functionality without paying for the upgrade, but then allows users who want a crisper interface to have one for only a few dollars more. My main worry is that Apple isn't going to like this, although I haven't found any documentation directly stating that it isn't allowed.

Comment: It's a brilliant idea, and simple enough to implement.  I guess you could just conditionally load the iPad based classes/nibs if they purchase the iAP.

Comment: I'm not sure how your two questions are different, except that you have answers on the other one.