# Running a universal app as a scaled iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I've seen tons of questions and answers regarding merging an iPhone and an iPad app into an universal app, but that isn't what I want to do. What I am going to do is use in app purchase to unlock an iPad interface and then display the correct interface using conditionals. If the interface is purchased, the app displays the iPad Nib, and if not, it just displays the same way as an iPhone application does (with the option to scale the app, etc). The conditionals are very simple and I have already implemented them, however the issue I run into is this: If the IAP is NOT purchased, the iPad displays the iPhone Nib, but not in the typical way. It is just in the corner with no option to scale it, rather than in the center with the black border that you usually see. Does anyone know how I can set it up so i fixes this issue? I'm a little stumped to be honest.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve what you are trying to do.  The iPad's OS determines what kind of app it is running (iPad compatible or iPhone resolution) and presents the view accordingly.  If you tell the OS through the app configuration that it can run on iPad, you will always get that kind of view.  Unless you do the view scaling manually on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Info.plist` file in an iOS app contains a key, `UIDeviceFamily`, which lists the devices that the app natively supports.  If the key's value is 1, or a array containing 1, the app natively supports iPhones and iPods Touch.  If the value is 2, or a array containing 2, the app natively supports iPads.

If `UIDeviceFamily` says the app supports iPads, then it will run the app in native iPad mode, not in iPhone-wrapper mode.

The `Info.plist` file is part of your app bundle, and you can't modify files in the app bundle.

So there is no way to enable or disable the system's native-iPad support at runtime.  You'll have to move your app's top-level view into a wrapper view that centers and scales its child, and use that wrapper view as the `UIWindow`'s subview.

[`UIDeviceFamily` in the *Information Property List Key Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now that I know it isn't possible, i'll have to cook something up to take care of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, unfortunately. The iPad will know that the app is iPad ready and will tell draw the screen at full size. Even if you showed iPhone xib file on the iPad, they would still be scaled to fit the full screen using the `UIViewAutoresizingMask` params you've set for them.

One thought would be to force the size of your `UIWindow` to be iPhone sized (remember to account for retina) and centered, but I'm not 100% sure how/if this would work. You may have to change each `UIView` frame. I'm not sure.